# Git submodules with docker-compose build

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, git-submodules

I'm trying to create a git superproject which contains submodules and have a `docker-compose.yml` file in the superproject to build all submodules.

Like discussed here:

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-10-project-structure-with-multiple-dockerfiles-and-docker-compose

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52389869

Example file structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── .git
├── .gitmodules
├── module1
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── .git
└── module2
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── .git
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  module1:
    image: module1
    build:
        context: ./module1
        dockerfile: Dockerfile

  module2:
    image: module2
    build:
        context: ./module2
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

This is also to orchestrate the environment but this is not relevant to my problems. 
This works fine initially.

However, the issue I'm running into, is if a module in its `Dockerfile` uses git. For example in a module I'm using:

```
git describe --tags || git rev-parse HEAD
```

to pass a git version to embed in my module's program.
This doesn't work because the `.git` folder in my submodule is no longer a folder but a file with a reference to `<superproject>/.git/modules/module1/`.

The output I'm getting when trying to run `docker-compose build` in `superproject` is:

```
fatal: not a git repository: <IMAGE_CWD>/../.git/modules/module1
```

So git is trying to reference a file which does not exist because `context: ./module1` is set in `docker-compose.yml`

I have no idea how to solve this. I don't want to expand the context in my `docker-compose.yml` because then I'd have to rewrite all `Dockerfile`'s.

I saw someone suggest dropping `git submodules` all together here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559410

This seems hacky.

I also tried to find if there's an option to have the `.git` folders in the submodules directly, oppposite of `git submodule absorbgitdirs` but found nothing.

It seems like a common usage, right? Is there a solution to this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @dacopenhagen Nope. I instead made a new git repo to house everything and removed the usage of submodules.